# FFMPEG won't stop after after alert "Past duration ..."

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to add 2 watermarks into a video.

It works well, like a charm. I just have this small problem: `ffmpeg` won't stop encoding unless I press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> to exit the process. Here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/in.mp4 -y /
-loop 1 -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/outro.png /
-loop 1 -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/newlayer.png /
-filter_complex "[1:v]fade=t=in:st=7:d=1:alpha=1[wm]; /
[2:v]fade=t=out:st=7:d=1:alpha=1[wm2]; /
[0:v][wm]overlay[v];[v][wm2]overlay" /
-codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfdk_aac /   
/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/videos/newvideo.avi
```

Here is my output console:

```
    ffmpeg version git-2015-09-06-db18b3d Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavcodec     57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavformat    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.0.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.05, start: 0.046440, bitrate: 1607 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1477 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/outro.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/newlayer.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] profile High, level 3.1
Output #0, avi, to '/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/videos/newvideo.avi':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    ISFT            : Lavf57.0.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.0.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.0.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> fade (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> fade (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.839836 too large    1475kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1207.7kbits/s    
frame=  251 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=110   frame=  251 fps= 22 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=143   frame=  251 fps= 21 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=176   frame=  251 fps= 20 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=201   frame=  251 fps= 20 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=222   frame=  251 fps= 19 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=254   frame=  251 fps= 18 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=287   frame=  251 fps= 18 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=319   frame=  251 fps= 17 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=352   frame=  251 fps= 16 q=28.0 size=    1504kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1230.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=385   frame=  251 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1580kB time=00:00:10.05 bitrate=1287.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=392    
video:1395kB audio:159kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.686170%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] frame I:2     Avg QP:18.98  size: 35646
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] frame P:109   Avg QP:20.17  size:  9465
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] frame B:140   Avg QP:20.37  size:  2329
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] consecutive B-frames: 15.9% 23.9% 15.5% 44.6%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] mb I  I16..4: 20.7% 56.8% 22.5%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] mb P  I16..4:  9.9% 12.2%  0.4%  P16..4: 42.1%  6.4%  1.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:27.3%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.7%  0.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 25.7%  1.0%  0.0%  direct: 1.9%  skip:70.2%  L0:41.5% L1:56.8% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] 8x8 transform intra:53.7% inter:90.7%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 19.7% 62.5% 15.3% inter: 5.2% 20.7% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 38% 23% 15% 23%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 16% 32%  2%  3%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 39% 21% 16%  3%  6%  6%  4%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 62% 16% 19%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:19.3% UV:19.3%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] ref P L0: 79.2%  7.0% 11.3%  2.3%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] ref B L0: 91.4%  8.0%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] ref B L1: 96.7%  3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x4afb4a0] kb/s:1138.61
[root@xxx ~]#
```

I guess it has to do with the PNG framerate not being the same as the mp4 (bold guess really), but any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why is `ffmpeg` processing my video forever?

What's happening is that `ffmpeg` gets to the end of one of your inputs (the video), but continues to encode because other inputs - in this case your images, set to `-loop 1` - are still going. This results in dropped frames until you terminate `ffmpeg` manually with <kbd>q</kbd> or 
<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>:

```
... drop=110
... drop=143
... drop=176
... drop=201
... drop=222
... 
... drop=385
... drop=392
```

### How do I tell `ffmpeg` to use the shortest video segment?

Depending on input and workflow, there are two options.

You can use the `-shortest` option (from [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)):

> ```
> -shortest (output)
>      Finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends.
> ```

or use the `shortest` parameter to the `overlay` filter (from the [filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)):

> ```
> shortest
>     If set to 1, force the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates. Default value is 0.
> ```

### I'm overlaying two watermarks using the `overlay` filter...

In this case, since you are using `filter_complex` to manage inputs, you would use `overlay` with the `shortest` option; so your command becomes:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/in.mp4 -y /
-loop 1 -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/outro.png /
-loop 1 -i /home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/newlayer.png /
-filter_complex "[1:v]fade=t=in:st=7:d=1:alpha=1[wm]; /
[2:v]fade=t=out:st=7:d=1:alpha=1[wm2]; /
[0:v][wm]overlay=shortest=1[v];[v][wm2]overlay=shortest=1" /
-codec:v libx264 -codec:a libfdk_aac /   
/home/twinuts/sd/videobot/www/videos/newvideo.avi
```

which then terminates when `in.mp4` is finished.